# Visual studio 2013 express missing Windows forms C# project template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I just installed a fresh copy of MS Visual Studio 2013 Express on Windows 8.1. After installing I checked out the new IDE. When I create a new C# project I need to select a project template like always. But the only options I have is: Store apps > Universal app, blank store app etc.

The problem is that I would like to create a winform project but I can't find the appropriate template. Do I need to download & install then Winform project template manually?

Edit:

This kind of project I would like to create. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492132.aspx

Comment: The term is "Thanks in Advance", not "Thanks in Advanced", and in any case, please don't use that on [so].

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you downloaded "Visual Studio Express for Windows":

> You can use the tools in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows to create innovative and compelling Windows Phone and Windows Store apps on Windows 8.1.

You want to download "Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop":

> Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop lets you take full advantage of Windows with XAML designers, a productive IDE, and a variety of programming languages including C#, Visual Basic, and C++. Choose between Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, and Win32, to target the Windows desktop with the right technology for your application and your skills.

I believe you can just [download](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-desktop) and install the "Windows Desktop" version and it'll all be fine - certainly in previous versions, you could have multiple editions installed, and they'd just be additive.

Comment: +1.  Also I think this should be on http://superuser.com...

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part =) I will check it out

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: No, I don't think so. "Software development tools" are explicitly part of the SO remit.